# JavaFX: Rendering selected ComboBox list item

Tags: listview, combobox, javafx-8, cell

In the test below the selected list item should appear together with a green marker. It works well for the initially selected item. However, it looks like #updateItem() isn't called when another item is selected which seems to be the reason of why the marker isn't updated properly.

```
public class ComboBoxCellFactoryTest extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage)
  {
    Parent content = createContent();
    Scene scene = new Scene(content, 400, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);    
    stage.show();
  }

  public Parent createContent()
  {
    FlowPane content = new FlowPane(10, 10);

    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();    
    combo.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"));
    combo.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
    combo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>()
    {
      @Override
      public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p)
      {
        return new ListCell<String>()
        {
          private final Rectangle rectangle;
          {
            rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10);
          }

          @Override
          protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
          {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null)
            {
              setText(null);
              setGraphic(null);
            }
            else
            {
              boolean selected = combo.getValue().equals(item);
              rectangle.setFill(selected ? Color.GREENYELLOW : Color.RED);
              setGraphic(rectangle);
              setText(item);
            }
          }
        };
      }
    });
    content.getChildren().add(combo);
    return content;
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug to me. A workaround (not formally tested, just a quick check!) might be to register a listener with the cell's selected property and manually force an updateItem, something like:

```
{
    rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10);
    selectedProperty().addListener((c, ov, nv) -> {
        updateItem(getItem(), getItem() == null);
    });
}
```

---

**Update**

Actually, it seems to be worse than a simple [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145588):

- `updateItem(...)` doesn't specify anything. It only contains blurb such as *can be overridden to allow for complete customisation of the cell*
- in particular, it doesn't specify *when* it is called - the only hint being a sentence in Cell's api doc *[updateItem] is called whenever the item in the cell changes*. With that design intention, the expectation as to an automatic update on changes to the cell's state - other than changing item - would be a usage error.
- but: the api doc contains a motivating example quite similar to the usage here (except that it changes the color of the text fill depending on goth selection and item value) - so the use case was at least in mind at the time of writing the doc
- the motivating example doesn't work at all, at a much deeper level than merely not updating the color when expected: it updates the color when *not* expected. Looks like the cell's own properties can't be relied on at the time of calling the updateItem

The see the last (and worst) bullet, run the example below (which is the motivating example wrapped into a simple app), select an item (note that the text color is not changed to white as intended) and scroll item-by-item: somewhere around the second page there's a line that's invisible (aka: text color is white). Happens because isSelected at the time of updateItem is unrelated to the selectedIndex (shown in the label below the list)

```
public class CellUpdateItemAndSelected extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Parent content = createContent();
        Scene scene = new Scene(content, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public Parent createContent() {
        Pane content = new VBox(10);
        ListView<Number> numberList = new ListView<>(createNumberData(20));
        // this is the motivating example from cell's api doc
        numberList.setCellFactory(cf -> {
            ListCell<Number> cell = new ListCell<Number>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(item == null ? "" : item.toString());
                    if (item != null) {
                        double value = item.doubleValue();
                        setTextFill(isSelected() ? Color.WHITE
                                : value == 0 ? Color.BLACK
                                        : value < 0 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
                        if (isSelected()) {
                            LOG.info("selected index/item: " + getIndex() + " / " + item);
                        }
                    }
                }

            };
            return cell;
        });

        Label selectedLabel = new Label();
        selectedLabel.textProperty().bind(numberList.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().asString());
        content.getChildren().addAll(numberList, selectedLabel);
        return content;
    }

    protected ObservableList<Number> createNumberData(int count) {
        ObservableList<Number> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = -3; i < count; i++) {
            data.add(i);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(CellUpdateItemAndSelected.class.getName());
}
```

---

**Update 2**

Work's started on the bug: in the patch core now calls updateItem(...) in updateSelected, like

```
public void updateSelected(boolean selected) {
    if (selected && isEmpty()) return;
    setSelected(selected);
    // fix for JDK-8145588
    updateItem(getItem(), isEmpty());
}
```

Would have to do the same for all other cell state properties...

Comment: The workaround works fine - being surprised about such a basic issue.

Comment: @wzberger uppened priority of your report - crossing fingers that it'll hold (at least it will get attention when somebody will lower it again ;-)